# Is there a way to load images from domain without changing localhost config host in webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

In my current `webpack.base.config` I have tried adding options public host into the loader images but I still couldn't load domain path for the images folder that contains the images I need to use. 
Is there a way to load both domain images and the ones in the localhost?

I have changed the loader to 'file' but still couldn't load the images that I need to load from the CDN. What do I need to do exactly to load external images outside the localhost but still being able to load local images from the assets? This is the first time I am editing webpack config files.. thanks for any help in advance!

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        //loader: 'file',
        loader: 'url',
        // options: {
        //   publicPath: 'https://asdgasdgasdgasdg.com'
        // }
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: To embed images from CDN, you just write simple HTML in vue templates. Ex: <img src='http://example.org/foobar.png' />.

Comment: doesnt work thats why i had to find an option through the webpack configs it. if i do it like above then i have to import the image by that it only works for one image but i cant v-for bunch of images

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use the proxy settings for this, e.g.

```
 devServer: {
    port: METADATA.port,
    host: METADATA.host,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    },
    contentBase: appConfig.dist,        
    proxy: {
       '*': 'http://localhost:8080', // REST service
    },
},
```

Comment: i tried this and on network tab says : cant get (https://mydomain.comm/static/image.jpeg), i still cant load the localhost static css & js files and cant load mydomain.com/randomfolder/randomimage

Comment: sadly i only get failed to load, with no error code and i believe its not CORS nor 404, probably its something within the webpack

Answer (score 0):

You just have to configure webpack for handling local images, maybe you can't load images from the CDN because the path or the method to fetch the images that you're using is wrong?

Comment: true, maybe because the cdn should target 'assets' folder since the the assets path resolves to there?, 'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets') . but still confused on how to deal with the assets through the webpack since i need it to target the cdn and the localhost assets directory too

Comment: Show how your trying to load the images from the CDN in vue.

Comment: `<img :src="item.img" alt="asg"/>`
`data(){`
`arr: [...Array(50)].map((item, index) => {`
`img: 'https://domain/images/three.jpeg'`

Comment: `<router-link v-for="(item,i) in arr" :to="'/user/'+ item.uid">
            <li class='users'>
              <img :src="item.img" alt="asg"/>`

can't coz i am looping through the array of images

Comment: Better post all this code in your question so I can understand it better.

Comment: the thing is if i put down all the code where as i don't really know where the issue is at, since it may be resolve path issue or importing every image neither do i really know if its in the conifg files of the webpack. so thats the reason i didnt want to put down all the code rather i just defined the issue where it lays on loading external absolute cdn images

Comment: I think your loader needs to be `url-loader` instead of `url`

Comment: i tried both also tried file-loader, does the url-loader allow including images from certain domain? i believe not because even though, those images data location comes from the database so it would be impossible to pre-compile those images within the webpack, i am getting frustrated on how i could configure this within the pack

Comment: Maybe is the CDN, you could try using something like vue-cli to generate a webpack project and see if ocurres the same.